# How can I make the background color of my span tags only showing on mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, dom

I got the following code to work, but I'm stuck on mouseover event. How can I make the background colors of  every span to only appear on  mouse event?

HTMl:

```
<div id="lipsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
<div id="output" class="button">&nbsp;Transform the Transcript!&nbsp;</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var lipsum = document.getElementById("lipsum");


var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.onclick = EventHandler;

function EventHandler() {
    lipsum.parentNode.replaceChild(newLipsum, lipsum);
    //lipsum.parentNode.removeChild(lipsum);
}


var sArr = lipsum.innerHTML.split(" ");
var colorArr = ["red", "orange","yellow" ];
var count = 0;
var newLipsum = document.createElement("div");

for (var i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
    var item = sArr[i];
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    var newText = document.createTextNode(item);
    var dotNode = document.createTextNode(" ");

   //newSpan.className = colorArr[count % 3];
    newSpan.id = "word" + i;

    newSpan.appendChild(newText);
    newSpan.appendChild(dotNode);

    newLipsum.appendChild(newSpan);


    count++;

}
var myspan = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (var i = 0; i < myspan.length; i++) {    
      myspan[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {    
      this.style.backgroundColor = "green";   

       setTimeout(function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "";
       }.bind(this), 1000);    
  }, false);

};
```

Here is a working JSFiddle without mouseover event on spans
http://jsfiddle.net/xE2cR/

Answer (score 0):

Use onmouseover event handler.

```
output.onmouseover = EventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

### OnMouseOver

```
output.onmouseover = EventHandler;
```

## [Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7cLRd/2/)

Comment: Thanks very much, but what I'm trying to do is to have the new text loaded but showing background colors only when mouseover the words. right now it is set  showing all colors when event is triggered. Sorry for the confusion.